# What will be effects of harnessing lightning?

Tags: electricity, charge, earth, atmospheric-science, lightning

In [Feynman's Lectures, volume 2, chapter 9](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_09.html#Ch9-S3), there is a mention of earth getting charged by thunderstorm lightning.

> It is the thunderstorms throughout the world that are charging the earth with an average of 1800 amperes, which is then being discharged through regions of fair weather.

Hypothetically, if we start to harness the energy from lightning, will it lead to build up of charges in earth? Will it have any effects on weather/climate? Or will the harnessed energy/charges find its way into earth by some means?

Comment: Might [earthscience.se] be better suited for these questions?

Comment: Not sure where else you expect the charge to end up?

Comment: More on [lightning as energy source](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+[lightning]+energy).

Answer (score 4):

If the electric charge from lightning is captured and harnessed through circuits, eventually it will reach the ground, but once there it will join the general discharge process mentioned by Feynman.  It won't lead to any build-up of charge.

Incidentally, it would be very difficult to harness lighting with sufficient regularity to make a difference to the human race's energy consumption.  The process of excess charge creation in clouds is widespread and unpredictable.  You'd have to cover a very wide area with densely spaced collection points to collect even a few lightning strikes a year.  The University of Florida Lightning Research Laboratory has 100 acres devoted to lightning gathering, but even in an area prone to thunderstorms, they are able to collect only about 6 strikes per year (http://www.lightning.ece.ufl.edu).  The battery storage facilities and number of collection points required for commercial application would be prohibitively expensive and probably energy inefficient.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, as a power engineer I'm fairly confident that this could be made energy efficient. But it will never be economical - barring the total collapse of all other electrical generation methods. It would drive the price of energy dramatically up.